# How do I run a ble scan when the screen is off in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an app that needs to search for BLE devices even when the screen is closed. It works until the moment I close the screen. It seems to go on a pause mode because when I turn on the screen it continues. I am using the flutter_reactive_ble package. I tried the flutter_blue package but it's the same.

Here's the code I used

```dart
import 'package:flutter_isolate/flutter_isolate.dart';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void someFunction(String arg) async {
  final flutterReactiveBle = FlutterReactiveBle();
  flutterReactiveBle.scanForDevices(
      // filter: ScanFilter.allGATT,
      withServices: [],
      scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency).listen((device) {
    //code for handling results
    print("device: ${device.id}");
  }, onError: (e) {
    //code for handling error
    print("error: $e");
  });
}
```

I tried to run the scan using a background service but the same thing happened. So far it's only getting to the point where the screen can be locked but never off. I also try using a foreground service but nothing changes.

I'm currently testing it on android

Comment: Are you testing on Android or iOS or both? Different platforms have different dependencies and behaviour.

Comment: I'm testing on Android